# Как найти в каком месте находится человек?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть база данных отелей, структура базы данных:

```
id - AUTO_INCREMENT
name_hotel - varchar
coordinates - multilinestring
```

И есть координаты человека, координаты формата ширина и долгота, например:

> 55.704219 37.772379

Как выполнять селект (поиск) по базе чтобы определить в каком из отелей находится человек?

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, но как должен выглядеть этот запрос?...

Comment: мало данных, допустим широта 55.704219, я не знаю масштаб ну допустим выведи с бд все значения больше (55.704219 - 0,01) и меньше (55.704219 + 0,01) и то же самое с долготой, нужный масштаб надо подобрать

Comment: @Jean-Claude я пытаюсь сделать так, но безуспешно (возвращает везде NULL):  select st_distance_sphere(
    GeomFromText(`coordinates`),
    POINT( 55.704219, 37.772379 )
)
as Distance2
FROM `hotels`

Comment: ну так выложи код

Comment: @Jean-Claude извиняюсь если глупый вопрос. но  я не совсем понимаю.. у меня есть координаты человека (ширина, долгота) и координаты места (multilinestring, у которого есть 2 или более точки которые соединяются в линию) и мне нужно определить, находится ли человек на линии или сколько метров удаленность от нее. Буду очень сильно благодарен если сможете мне помочь с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень ясна суть вопроса, но можно например прикинуть что человек находится в том отеле к которому он ближе всего по координатам

дистанцию от места я считал примерно такой выборкой

```
(((acos(sin(( :lat * pi()/180)) * sin((c.G1*pi()/180))+cos(( :lat *pi()/180)) * cos((c.G1*pi()/180)) * cos((( :lon - c.G2)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance
```

:lat - соответственно широта нахождения человека

:lon - долгота

c.G1 и c.G2 - соответственно  широта и долгота объекта

Ну и получается что вам нужно будет сделать поиск по таблице отелей, отсортировать дистанцию по возрастанию и выбрать первый результат.

Сразу скажу формулу писал эту не сам, нашел когда то на просторах интернета.